# How do characters act so fast in movies?

Tags: film-techniques, production, editing

I was watching The Hills Have Eyes (2006) and in one scene a zombie is searching to kill someone. In this scene a human and his dog are hiding from the zombie, but the dog unfortunately made some noise.

[image]

Suddenly the zombie turned back within seconds when he heard the noise.

[image]

But now the man and the dog escaped (***it almost looks like they disappeared to me***) so fast from the place.

[image]

I saw this thing in so many movies, how do characters act so fast in movies?

Comment: Same way some characters can beat lot of people. Many dudes holding two guns in open can kill many people in crossfire, without getting hit

Comment: Are you talking about the characters and how they acted so fast *inside the story of the film* (as you question suggests) or do you actually want to know how it is *filmed so fast with the actors* acting so fast (as the question's tags suggest)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Movies don't always show events happening in real time. To avoid a 5 seconds scene of the zombie walking around the house to the point where our characters stood, directors sometimes cut it out and just show the crucial moments.

It is implied that the characters managed to, somehow, hide (and not showing how they did it can help making the reveal more exciting!).

Answer (score 2):

Suspensión of disbelief is needed to believe they moved so fast. That said, fearing being killed or worse by a mutant/zombie is enough to get anyone moving so fast. Adrenaline is a great drug for that.